# How to store jQuery function's result and display it on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've stuck into this.. I've jquery on a page which runs according to value user put and display result on same page. its working fine but i dont want to display that on that but on next page.
How to do that?
I've heard that through ajax call i can give the result to php and can store there but i dont know how to do that or if there is easy way then that?

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="age" class="col-sm-7">&bull; What is the age of the oldest person applying? </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select type="age" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="age" name="age">
                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Under 35">Under 35</option>
                <option value=">35 - 44">35 - 44</option>
                <option value=">45 - 54">45 - 54</option>
                <option value=">55 - 59">55 - 59</option>
                <option value=">60 - 64">60 - 64</option>
                <option value=">65 - 69">65 - 69</option>
                <option value=">70 - 74">70 - 74</option>
                <option value=">75 - 79">75 - 79</option>
                <option value="80 +">80 +</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="dependant" class="col-sm-7">&bull; How many additional dependants will be covered?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select type="person" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="person" name="person">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="01">01</option>
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <option value="03">03</option>
                <option value="04">04</option>
                <option value="05">05</option>
                <option value="06">06</option>
                <option value="07">07</option>
                <option value="08">08</option>
                <option value="09">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="next" name="next" value="Next">
</form>

<div class="alli"> $0</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#next").click(function update_pricing() {

        //pricing data for pricing table
        var pricing_data = {

            single: {
                "0"       : [0, 0, 0],
                "Under 35": [46.75, 124.25, 152.25],
                ">35 - 44": [51.75, 138.25, 168.50],
                ">45 - 54": [59.00, 152.25, 195.50],
                ">55 - 59": [63.25, 160.00, 209.00],
                ">60 - 64": [71.00, 170.50, 220.50],
                ">65 - 69": [58.50, 144.25, 187.00],
                ">70 - 74": [71.25, 187.50, 229.00],
                ">75 - 79": [77.50, 225.00, 303.75],
                "80 +"    : [97.25, 275.75, 366.00]
            },
            couple: {
                "0"       : [0, 0, 0],
                "Under 35": [88.75, 236.75, 288.50],
                ">35 - 44": [99.00, 262.75, 320.75],
                ">45 - 54": [112.00, 288.50, 371.25],
                ">55 - 59": [120.25, 303.75, 397.50],
                ">60 - 64": [134.75, 323.75, 419.25],
                ">65 - 69": [111.25, 275.25, 355.50],
                ">70 - 74": [135.25, 356.50, 435.25],
                ">75 - 79": [147.75, 427.75, 577.00],
                "80 +"    : [184.50, 523.50, 696.00]
            },
            family: {
                "0"       : [0, 0, 0],
                "Under 35": [116.50, 310.50, 379.00],
                ">35 - 44": [129.50, 345.25, 421.00],
                ">45 - 54": [147.25, 379.00, 488.25],
                ">55 - 59": [157.50, 399.00, 522.25],
                ">60 - 64": [177.00, 425.25, 551.50],
                ">65 - 69": [146.25, 361.25, 467.25],
                ">70 - 74": [177.50, 468.75, 572.50],
                ">75 - 79": [194.00, 562.25, 759.00],
                "80 +"    : [242.50, 688.50, 914.75]
            }
        }

        var age_order = {
            "0"       : 0,
            "Under 35": 1,
            ">35 - 44": 2,
            ">45 - 54": 3,
            ">55 - 59": 4,
            ">60 - 64": 5,
            ">65 - 69": 6,
            ">70 - 74": 7,
            ">75 - 79": 8,
            "80 +"    : 9
        }

        var age_fields = $('select[id^="dep_age_"], #age');

        var family_size = parseInt($('#person').val());

        var max_age = "0";

        function do_update() {

            var pricing_set;

            //grab appropriate pricing set from pricing data
            if (family_size == 0) {
                pricing_set = pricing_data.single[max_age];
            } else if (family_size === 1) {
                pricing_set = pricing_data.couple[max_age];
            } else if (family_size > 1) {
                pricing_set = pricing_data.family[max_age];
            }

            var price_carrier = $('.alli'); //put price values here in pricing tables

            //if appropriate pricing set is grabbed (not true when either one of age or family size not selected)
            if (pricing_set) {

                //put price values in all pricing tables
                price_carrier.each(function (i, el) {

                    //if family members are more than 6, increase prices by 30%
                    if (family_size > 6) {
                        $(el).text('$' + (pricing_set[i] + pricing_set[i] * 0.3).toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        $(el).text('$' + pricing_set[i].toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        age_fields.each(function () {
            if (age_order[$(this).val()] > age_order[max_age]) {
                max_age = $(this).val();
            }
        });
        do_update();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use AJAX/PHP then you can use the browser's localStorage or sessionStorage as introduced in HTML5, as:

If your result is stored in an element with `id= "results"`
then you can store it in locaStorage as:

```
localStorage.setItem('titles', $('#results').text());
```

and to fetch the item on any other page use:

```
var myItem = localStorage.getItem('titles');
```

More about local and session storage here:
 [Local Storage](http://Local%20Storage)
[Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: @FaheemFerozi https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage has a list of supported platforms.

Comment: Yes, as long as the browser supports HTML5. local and session storages are a feature  off HTML5.

Comment: @FaheemFerozi No problem bro!