# sessionStorage is not passing string

Tags: javascript, session-storage

**First page**

```
sessionStorage.myvar=no;
```

**Second page**

```
var display=sessionStorage.myvar;
```

Here I am trying to pass a session variable through pages. The `sessionvariable` is only supporting numbers, if I try to send string, it is saying error.

First error comes if it starts with number and Second error comes if it starts with alphabet
**Snapshot:**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store jQuery function's result and display it on other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818436/how-to-store-jquery-functions-result-and-display-it-on-other-page)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `string` with quotes. like below

```
sessionStorage.myvar='no';
```

or

```
sessionStorage.myvar="no";
```